# Highlight Current Navbar Link?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Update!**

I've done about 4 hours more research and have designed my code to work without having hard-coded directories/paths.

The idea is that the `currentLinkFunction()` function is called from the `onload` attribute in the `<a>` tag.

The if statement below sets the source element to bold if the page location is equal to the `href` within the `<a>` tag.

```
function currentLinkFunction() {
    if (window.location.pathname == window.event.srcElement.href.pathname) {
        window.event.srcElement.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    }
}
```

That was premise, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the full page:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Smith</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1 class="site-title">Smith</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a onload="currentLinkFunction()" class="nav-link" href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a onload="currentLinkFunction()" class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a onload="currentLinkFunction()" class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a onload="currentLinkFunction()" class="nav-link" href="#">Software</a></li>
            <li><a onload="currentLinkFunction()" class="nav-link" href="#">Photograhpy</a></li>
            <li><a onload="currentLinkFunction()" class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <footer>
        <h2 id="site-copywrite">Designed by <b>Smith</b></h2>
    </footer>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function currentLinkFunction() {            
            if (window.location.pathname == window.event.srcElement.href.pathname) {
                window.event.srcElement.style.fontWeight = "bold";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

**Original Post:**

I'm trying to set a style to my navbar that the current page link is bold.

The way I'm doing this is calling a function onload that sets the style if href = index.html.

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Smithy000/qb4mgara/)

HTML

```html
<ul>
  <li><a onload="currentLinkFunction()" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a onload="currentLinkFunction()" href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a onload="currentLinkFunction()" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a onload="currentLinkFunction()" href="#">Software</a></li>
  <li><a onload="currentLinkFunction()" href="#">Photograhpy</a></li>
  <li><a onload="currentLinkFunction()" href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```js
function currentLinkFunction() {
  if (location.href == "index.html") {
    location.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the script is being called for every element.

The solution is to use this script once and loop through each element of the `nav-link` class.

```
var i = 0;
var navLinkCount = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link");

for (i; i < navLinkCount.length; i = i + 1) {
    if (window.location.pathname === navLinkCount[i].getAttribute("href")) {
        navLinkCount[i].style.fontWeight = "bold";
        navLinkCount[i].style.backgroundColor = "#E0E0E0";
    }
}
```

Also the `===` operator has to be used when comparing values in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

`location.href` returns the **full** URL.

> The href property sets or returns the entire URL of the current page.

<sub>http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp</sub>

You are looking for [`location.pathname`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_pathname.asp).

> The pathname property sets or returns the pathname of a URL.

1. Replace `location.href` with `location.pathname`.
2. `location.style` is not valid because `location` is not a DOM object. So you can add an `id` or `class` to the link to `index.html` or you can find the object using javascript like below:

```js
  function currentLinkFunction() {
    if (location.pathname == "index.html") {
      document.querySelector('a[href="index.html"]').style.fontWeight = "bold";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I never knew that.
It's still not working though, is there an issue with the way I'm trying to add the styling?